# How to restructure the Object to specific format in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I need to restructure the current object what i'm getting from API response to desired object.

Current Output

```
let temp = [
    {
      "imagePath": "",
      "imageDescription": [
        {
          "language": "en",
          "text": "Today's News Updated"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "imagePath": "",
      "imageDescription": [
        {
          "language": "en",
          "text": "test"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "imagePath": "",
      "imageDescription": [
        {
          "language": "de",
          "text": "test"
        }
      ]
    },
   
  
 
  ]
```

Desired output

```
let temp = {
"imagesList": {
    "en": [{
       "imagePath": "",
       "text": "Today's News Updated"
     },
     {
       "imagePath": "",
       "text": "test"
     }],
     "de": [{
       "imagePath": "",
       "text": "test"
     }]
   }
}
```

How to achieve this in angular by typescript so that i can render in the view

Please find the below Sandbox Link
[Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-sanderson-cwudmy?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Please share the code with which you fetch the data from the backend.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner Here is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-sanderson-cwudmy?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgA4FcyoLZwDmKA3gFDKXLAHEAKcYAFgFzIDOYUohA3BVRpEIAEQjsE3DGGAB7EG3TYwYiVJnyA2gF1%20AXzJkwATwwoAMnBCEsw5AF5kAIgggnyAD7OAJhCf8yUEhYRBQlHFVJYGk5EGRyKmQAGysbYTZLa1tifkTIAA8wNk5ua31DJIgwZEg8DEVMHHxhHQdkTQFKBMSqJyF6RiYnNicnABpOnr7aUXEomPlh9smeqm7VjecUrOEllzcJzc2nArA9gBVZbzhjAHJ2ZAA5CAB3B4BVDGvIbycVjYMm20kz0hzW-0o02EDGYe3GEOc-VmamiGjcbA6R3BWNWTm2aWIe1c8JxU1Oe0gnD%20pMBG2BiVBk3WUyRMKGIxJGyhxEi6liS0xOOZpLxqWyfhGvk5pMh5JGlLOCIZCPpVEZwMC4Gg8CQaBmAHVgMxeajYvFJqzBsUuDwwZRTtbSoQJgZNcEdSgAEriLBJarMpHsczAThsYVUTQAawgxmocUyBIg2gA-IoDUamCaFiAdLk1WRXQh5JxkFAfX62rUMAA6MveLBIAA83vYvrAAD4ABSdxAIMbIABucCSAEoHO3zYkiyASyRqDMgyHqno2r285Rp7P59DBv2kVm0cgV44h0l18gYLIoMhO5v-ckxcJ%206cj8hZDBtzy5nz5GPw5RgA-TsAEJO3xcU40-cRg04Ec-yVQQFxgsBNHA4RtDaTQ50tZhnwgQoj10BCN3kGQQCwCBz2VTYEU7QNkNQx9iAwuAHmaYhDWNb9TS0bQR2rbB2CYTt-x6HCmDtI5TgRPQRxBQxEjLMAsCgOI1wLftsKQpcwxXWSAk3WRKmrJJZEITsy1bP0R14IA)

```js
interface InputImage {
    imagePath: string;
    imageDescription: InputDescription[];
}

type Language = "en" | "de";

interface InputDescription {
    language: Language;
    text: string;
}

let temp: InputImage[] = [
    {
        "imagePath": "",
        "imageDescription": [
            {
                "language": "en",
                "text": "Today's News Updated"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "imagePath": "",
        "imageDescription": [
            {
                "language": "en",
                "text": "test"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "imagePath": "",
        "imageDescription": [
            {
                "language": "de",
                "text": "test"
            }
        ]
    },
]

interface ImageWithDescription {
    imagePath: string,
    text: string,
}

interface Result {
    imagesList: {
        [key in Language]?: ImageWithDescription[];
    }
}

const result = temp.reduce<Result>((acc, val) => {
    const { imagesList } = acc;
    const { imagePath, imageDescription } = val;
    for (const { language, text } of imageDescription) {
        if (!(language in imagesList)) {
            imagesList[language] = [{ imagePath, text }];
            continue;
        }
        
        (imagesList[language] as ImageWithDescription[]).push({
            imagePath,
            text
        })
    }

    return acc;
}, { imagesList: {} });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my, very naive, approach to this issue:

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({ .. })
export class FoobarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Assuming you fetch your data via httpClient
    this.data$ = of([
      {
        imagePath: '',
        imageDescription: [
          {
            language: 'en',
            text: 'Today\'s News Updated'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        imagePath: '',
        imageDescription: [
          {
            language: 'en',
            text: 'test'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        imagePath: '',
        imageDescription: [
          {
            language: 'de',
            text: 'test'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]).pipe(map((data) => {
      const enList = [];
      const deList = [];
      data.forEach((item) => {
        item.imageDescription.forEach((description) => {
          if (description.language === 'de') {
            deList.push({imagePath: item.imagePath, text: description.text});
          }
          if (description.language === 'en') {
            enList.push({imagePath: item.imagePath, text: description.text});
          }
        });
      });
        return {
          imagesList: {
            en: enList,
            de: deList,
          }
        };
      }
    ));
  }
}
```

There's plenty of spots to improve for better performance and a more dynamic approach. But it should give you a good hint for the start.